# Как вставить Unit Test в приложение WPF?

Tags: юнит-тесты, wpf, тестирование

Здравствуйте, искал в гугле, вроде простой вопрос, но ничего не нашел. Подскажите, как использовать тесты для работы в `tdd-style` вместе с `WPF`?

Answer (score 1):

Для тестирования интерфейса WPF существует система классов [AutomationPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer.aspx).

Unit тестирование обычно интерфейс не подразумевает, а наиболее используемый с WPF паттерн MVVM предоставляет замечательный уровень VM прямо-таки созданный для модульного тестирования.

Что касается модульного, кстати, в 2012 студии добавилась отличная возможность использовать тесты прямо в проекте разработки.

Comment: Spawn, можно посмотреть пошаговое руководство как это использовать. Где эта возможность использовать тесты в проекте разработки? не могу найти подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот, например - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182532.aspx

Вообще, после добавления ссылки на Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll можно пометить любой публичный класс как TestClass и соответственно все публичные в нём методы с атрибутом TestMethod автоматически будут восприниматься студией как тестовые.

Comment: Все теперь, все понятно, спасибо что объяснили.